# How to connect to AWS Simple AD LDAP using Spring LDAP Template

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, ldap

I created Simple AD in AWS and also Joined a Windows EC2 instance to that Simple AD. But the use case is to access Simple AD from a Java application(using Spring LDAP Template) and create/update a user inside that AD.
Here are the application.properties I am providing

```
ldap.partitionSuffix=dc=test, dc=directory, dc=com
ldap.principal=uid=Administrator
ldap.password=#######
ldap.port=389
ldap.url=ldap://172.35.51.160:389
```

The application is not able to connect to Simple AD.
Giving Connection time out Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the code in the same VPC as Simple AD. 172.35.51.160 is private IP address in your VPC.

If you want access Simple AD server from public Internet, then put ELB and HA Proxy in front of Simple AD.

ELB -> HA Proxy -> Simple AD.